# Trying to draw a bitmap on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, bitmap

I'm just learing how to program the blackberry and trying to display a bitmap on the screen, here is the code:

```
public MyScreen()
{        
    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("MyTitle2");
    LabelField lb = new LabelField("hello ted2");
    add(lb);

    Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/icon2.png");
    BitmapField fd= new BitmapField(logoBitmap, Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    add(fd); 
}
```

The label is drawn but not the bitmap.

Answer (score 2):

Your path is wrong, copy the image into /res/img. To retrieve that, use the file name only.

```
Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("icon2.png");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the two fields into a `VerticalFieldManager`:

```
public MyScreen()
{        
    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager();

    // Set the displayed title of the screen       
    setTitle("MyTitle2");
    LabelField lb = new LabelField("hello ted2");
    vfm.add(lb);

    Bitmap logoBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("res/icon2.png");
    BitmapField fd= new BitmapField(logoBitmap);
    vfm.add(fd); 

    add(vfm);
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for answering my quastion, but...it still does not work.

Comment: Make sure your path to the PNG file is correct. If it's not, I think `getBitmapResource` just returns `null`, so no exception gets thrown.